# Dynamic upper bound for foreach loop

Tags: input, foreach

I want to read the upper bound for my foreach loop from a file. I've tried the following, but it gives all manner of errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo}
42
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\foreach\x in {1,...,\input{foo}} {\x,}
\end{document}
```

I've also tried saving the `\input{foo}` into a command, and then putting that command name in as the foreach's upper bound. But that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `catchfile`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,catchfile}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
42
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef\upperlimit{\jobname.dat}{}
\foreach\x in {1,...,\upperlimit} {\x, }
\end{document}
```

(I used a different name for the file in order not to clobber any of my files.)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to change the contents of foo to latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo}
\def\limit{42}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\input{foo}
\foreach\x in {1,...,\limit} {\x,}
\end{document}
```

If you just want "42" you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo}
42
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\newread\io%
\openin\io=foo%
\read\io to\limit%
\closein\io%

\foreach\x in {1,...,\limit} {\x,}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well done. I was looking for a solution using custom `list`, in vain.

Comment: PGF has already a temporary openin `\r@pgf@reada` for scratching stuff in case needed.